# Trying to simulate an Overwatch loot box opening program in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

So basically I am trying to recreate opening a loot box in Overwatch into a runnable program in python. I'm trying to make it take four random items in an array and display them each time the user types 'open' to open a box. After every box is opened, I want it to loop and ask if they want to open another one, or if they don't and then stop the program. Here's my code so far:

```
import random

# welcome
print("Welcome to the Overwatch Loot Box Simulator!")

OpenBox = input("Type 'open' to open a loot box!")

OverwatchSkins = [
    'Legendary: Oni Genji',
    'Epic: Frostbite Pharah',
    'Rare: Banana Winston',
    'Rare: Cobalt Reinhardt',
    'Epic: Synaesthesia Lucio',
    'Legendary: Lone Wolf Hanzo',
    'Rare: Rose Widowmaker',
    'Rare: Celestial Mercy',
    'Epic: Carbon Fiber D.VA',
    'Legendary: Dr. Junkenstein Junkrat',
    'Epic: Nihon Genji',
    'Rare: Blood Reaper',
    'Rare: Ebony McCree',
    'Epic: Demon Hanzo',
    'Rare: Peridot Ana',
    'Rare: Lemonlime D.VA',
    'Epic: Taegeukgi D.VA',
    'Legendary: Mei-rry Mei',
    'Legendary: Augmented Sombra',
    'Rare: Technomancer Symmetra',
    'Rare: Mud Roadhog'
]

if OpenBox == "open":
    print(random.choice(OverwatchSkins))
```

the OverwatchSkins array would just be filled up with more names later on. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: At least bother to format your question correctly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap everything in a `while(True)`-Loop and use `break` to stop the loop, if the user puts in something other than *open*.

Make sure that only the input and output are in the loop, since you don't want to redefine your list on every pass.

```
import random
print("Welcome to the Overwatch Loot Box Simulator!")
OverwatchSkins = ['Legendary: Oni Genji', 'Epic: Frostbite Pharah', 'Rare: Banana Winston', 'Rare: Cobalt Reinhardt', 'Epic: Synaesthesia Lucio', 'Legendary: Lone Wolf Hanzo', 'Rare: Rose Widowmaker', 'Rare: Celestial Mercy', 'Epic: Carbon Fiber D.VA', 'Legendary: Dr. Junkenstein Junkrat', 'Epic: Nihon Genji', 'Rare: Blood Reaper', 'Rare: Ebony McCree', 'Epic: Demon Hanzo', 'Rare: Peridot Ana', 'Rare: Lemonlime D.VA', 'Epic: Taegeukgi D.VA', 'Legendary: Mei-rry Mei', 'Legendary: Augmented Sombra', 'Rare: Technomancer Symmetra', 'Rare: Mud Roadhog']

while(True):
    OpenBox = input("Type 'open' to open a loot box! ")
    if OpenBox == "open":
        print(random.choice(OverwatchSkins))
    else:
        break
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for this! Do you have any idea of how to put out four random items from the array each time a "box" is opened?

Comment: @mastermind, have a look at [`random.sample()`](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/random.html#random.sample)

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Christian, something like the following:

```
import random
import sys

OverwatchSkins = ['Legendary: Oni Genji', 'Epic: Frostbite Pharah', 'Rare: Banana Winston', 'Rare: Cobalt Reinhardt', 'Epic: Synaesthesia Lucio', 'Legendary: Lone Wolf Hanzo', 'Rare: Rose Widowmaker', 'Rare: Celestial Mercy', 'Epic: Carbon Fiber D.VA', 'Legendary: Dr. Junkenstein Junkrat', 'Epic: Nihon Genji', 'Rare: Blood Reaper', 'Rare: Ebony McCree', 'Epic: Demon Hanzo', 'Rare: Peridot Ana', 'Rare: Lemonlime D.VA', 'Epic: Taegeukgi D.VA', 'Legendary: Mei-rry Mei', 'Legendary: Augmented Sombra', 'Rare: Technomancer Symmetra', 'Rare: Mud Roadhog']

while True:
    key = raw_input('\nType "open" to open a loot box!\n(Type "q" to exit.)\nYour input: ')
    if key.lower()=='q':
        sys.exit()
    elif key.lower()=='open':
        print random.choice(OverwatchSkins)
    else:
        print "Invalid input, try again!"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a little more than you asked for. The following adds a probability to each item, so that 'Rare' items are chosen less often than 'Epic', and 4 items are chosen.

The example has been reformatted to use Python conventions, eg `snake_case` rather than `CamelCase` for variable names.

```
import random

overwatch_skins = [
    # skin list here
]

frequency = {
    'Legendary': 2,
    'Rare': 1,
    'Epic': 4
}
# type is to the left of the first colon
types = [skin.split(':')[0] for skin in overwatch_skins]
# map types onto weightings
weightings = [frequency[type] for type in types]

print("Welcome to the Overwatch Loot Box Simulator!")
while True:
    reply = input("Type 'open' to open a loot box!")
    if reply != "open":
        break
    print(random.choices(overwatch_skins, weightings, k=4))

>>> python choices.py
['Legendary: Dr. Junkenstein Junkrat', 'Rare: Ebony McCree', 'Epic: Frostbite Pharah', 'Epic: Demon Hanzo']
['Epic: Taegeukgi D.VA', 'Rare: Lemonlime D.VA', 'Legendary: Mei-rry Mei', 'Epic: Nihon Genji']
```

Note the use of list comprehensions, a way of building lists from other lists in Python:

```
types = [skin.split(':')[0] for skin in overwatch_skins]
weightings = [frequency[type] for type in types]
```

which you can explore by putting `print()` calls after each, and the use of `random.choices` to return four weighted choices at a time.

Normally you would keep the 'rare', 'epic' and 'legendary' aspects of an item separate from the description, eg using tuples. So:

```
('Legendary', 'Oni Genji'),
```

rather than:

```
'Legendary: Oni Genji',
```